# Set automatically value in a textbox after autocomplete javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I have 4 textbox that are connected each other in my database, the values are: Name surname, team, society, country.

I have already created an autocomplete method for all the values; infact if i try to write a name/society ecc, the method search in the database if the values exist and recommend values. Another thing that i have already implemented is that if I select a name surname and a team (or other 2 values) it suggests you society and country or what you did not select that are collegated with the other values.

What do i have to do to set automatically the values, without using the select of the user(what i have to do to set automaticcaly the textbox value of the result of the query)? Thank you.
I am using Asp.net mvc and javascript.

Edit: this the code.
Html:

```
@{
    string autocompletePrefix = "address";
}
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.CustomLabelFor(model => model.PlayerId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10" style="display:inline-flex;">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        @Html.TextBox("Player", null, null, new { @id = autocompletePrefix + "PlayerName", @class = "ui-autocomplete-input form-control" })
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button id="@autocompletePrefix-PlayerSearcher" class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list" id="@autocompletePrefix-playerIconList"></span>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-autocomplete ui-front btn-group-vertical"></div>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PlayerId, new { @id = autocompletePrefix + "PlayerId" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PlayerId)
                </div>
            </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('ready readyAgain', function () {
            address = AutocompleteTeamModule('@autocompletePrefix', '@Url.Action("GetHintsForPlayers", "Addresses", new { })', '@Url.Action("GetHintsForTeam", "Addresses", new { })', '@Url.Action("GetHintsForSocieties", "Addresses", new { })', '@Url.Action("GetHintsForCountry", "Addresses", new { })');
        initMultipleSelection();
    });

    </script>
```

Javascript:

```
function AutocompleteTeamModule( _prefixHtmlId, _hintsForPlayer,_hintsForTeam,_hintsForSociety,_hintsForCountry)
{
    init: function () {
    $("#" + myObj.prefixHtmlId + "-PlayerSearcher").click(function () {
                myObj.PlayerSearcherClick = true;
                $('#' + myObj.prefixHtmlId + 'PlayerName').autocomplete("option", "minLength", 0);
                var value = $("#" + myObj.prefixHtmlId + "PlayerId").val();
                if( value != "")
                    $('#' + myObj.prefixHtmlId + 'PlayerName').autocomplete("search", $("#" + myObj.prefixHtmlId + "PlayerId").val());
                else
                    $('#' + myObj.prefixHtmlId + 'CountryName').autocomplete("search", "");
                $('#' + myObj.prefixHtmlId + 'PlayerName').trigger("focus");
                $("#" + myObj.prefixHtmlId + "-PlayerLoader").toggleClass("hide", false);
                $("#" + myObj.prefixHtmlId + "-PlayerIconList").toggleClass("hide", true);
                $("#" + myObj.prefixHtmlId + "-PlayerCountry").toggleClass("hide", false);
                $('#' + myObj.prefixHtmlId + 'PlayerName').autocomplete("option", "minLength", 2);
            });

              $("#" + myObj.prefixHtmlId + "PlayerName").autocomplete({
                minLength: 2, autoFocus: true, source: function (term, resp) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: myObj.hintsPlayerUrl,
                        data: { "id": term.term + "-" + $("#" + myObj.prefixHtmlId + "PlayerId").val() },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#" + myObj.prefixHtmlId + "-PlayerLoader").toggleClass("hide", true);
                            $("#" + myObj.prefixHtmlId + "-PlayerIconList").toggleClass("hide", false);
                            myObj.PlayerNameData = data.slice();

                            resp(data, function (data) {
                                return data;
                            });
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, txt, err) {
                            iride_error_handler(xhr, txt, err);
                        }
                    })
                },
                select: function (e, data) {
                  var pa=$("#" + myObj.prefixHtmlId + "PlayerId").val();
                    $("#" + myObj.prefixHtmlId + "PlayerId").val(data.item.value);
                    $("#" + myObj.prefixHtmlId + "-PlayerLoader").toggleClass("hide", true);
                    $("#" + myObj.prefixHtmlId + "-PlayerIconList").toggleClass("hide", false);
                    pa = data.item.value;
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var teamisSet = $("#" + myObj.prefixHtmlId + "TeamId").val();
                    if (teamisSet == "")
                        $('#' + myObj.prefixHtmlId + 'TeamName').autocomplete("search", "-" + pa);
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var societyisSet = $("#" + myObj.prefixHtmlId + "SocietyId").val();
                    if (provinceisSet == "")
                        $('#' + myObj.prefixHtmlId + 'ProvinceName').autocomplete("search", "-" + pa);
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var countryisSet = $("#" + myObj.prefixHtmlId + "CountryId").val();
                    if(countryisSet == "")
                    $('#' + myObj.prefixHtmlId + 'CountryName').autocomplete("search", "-" + $("#" + myObj.prefixHtmlId + "CountryId").val());
                    e.preventDefault();
                },
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    if (ui.item.value != " ") {
                        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                    }
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might provide some code samples or be more specific in what components you are using.

Maybe you can use just jQuery (javascript):

```js
$('#textboxID').val('new value of textbox');
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on the JQuery suggestion-

I'd definitely like to see some code but based on what I *think* your code looks like,

If you're talking about changing the value of selectors based on user input on other selectors, you can use a `switch` or `if else` inside your click handler. If this is a very data-heavy process there's sure to be a more efficient way to do it but if this is small enough it would go something like this-

```
    $('submitbutton').click(function() {
       if ($('firstselector').val() == 'certain value') {
          $('secondselector').val("associated value 1");
          $('thirdselector').val("associated value 2");
       } else if ($('firstselector').val() == 'another certain value') {
          // so on and so forth
       };
    });
```

a switch, if too many options available- to clean up the code

```
    $('submitbutton').click(function() {
       switch ($('firstselector').val()) {
          case: 'certain value'
             $('secondselector').val("associated value 1");
             $('thirdselector').val("associated value 2");
             break; 
          case: 'another certain value'
             // so on and so forth
             break;
       };
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have add a part of my code.